# hiding newline in the string which gets key and value pair in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, split, newline

I need to hide newline in the string which gets key and value pair in NSDictionary. I put strings as  values in NSDictionary.But my problem is, when i run my app it shows " \n " in labels or buttons i defined. I changed all the strings- hard coded-  with keys defined in my plist in my project.

i.e: in my plist:

```
key: toOtherBank
value: Send it to \n the other bank account
```

and in mycode:

```
[dictPayment setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:[classUsed getValue: @"toOtherBank"]];
```

Could you help me to hide this new line in the string that i assign as a value of a key in my plist .

Comment: Please go through my answer, certainly it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove the newline character, just do this on the string:

```
[[myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Or more simple:

```
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

For achieving this you just need to remove new line character first that you can do as…

```
NSString *keyString = [UtilityFunctions getValue: @"toOtherBank"];
[keyString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
[dictPayment setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:keyString];
```